# git add command staging unexpected extra files

Tags: git

i encountered a really strange problem when use git, detailed as following:

I pull a package from remote and git status show that it's update to date:

```
XXXService weiheng$ git status
On branch mainline
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/mainline'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean

XXXService weiheng$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
```

then i modified a file, git status show as following:

```
XXXService weiheng$ git status
On branch mainline
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/mainline'.
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

modified:   configuration/app/XXXService.conf

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Ok, all seems look fine in present. However, when use git add to stage the change, three extra files be added too:

```
XXXService weiheng$ git add configuration/app/XXXService.cfg
XXXService weiheng$ git status
On branch mainline
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/mainline'.
Changes to be committed:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

modified:   configuration/app/XXXService.conf
new file:   configuration/tomcat-setup-env-Alpha/RemoteDebugging.xml
new file:   configuration/tomcat-setup-env-Beta/RemoteDebugging.xml
new file:   configuration/tomcat-setup-env-Gamma/RemoteDebugging.xml
```

I didn't set up any hooks in git. I attempted to reset to HEAD for these three files, but it did work, and git status show the same as above.

```
XXXService weiheng$ git reset HEAD configuration/tomcat-setup-env-Alpha/RemoteDebugging.xml
XXXService weiheng$ git status
On branch mainline
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/mainline'.
Changes to be committed:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

modified:   configuration/app/XXXService.conf
new file:   configuration/tomcat-setup-env-Alpha/RemoteDebugging.xml
new file:   configuration/tomcat-setup-env-Beta/RemoteDebugging.xml
new file:   configuration/tomcat-setup-env-Gamma/RemoteDebugging.xml
```

Thanks in advance! And looking forward to ...

Comment: I have no idea what's going on here, but I will note that before your `git reset` you had configuration/app/XXXservice **.conf** marked modified, and after your `git reset` you had configuration/ **brazil-config** /app/XXXservice **.cfg**  marked modified.  These do not match at all.

Comment: @torek sorry, it's a typo. I changed it to XXXService.conf

Comment: One still has `brazil-config` in it and the others don't.  And, if you're editing Git's output, you're probably making it harder for anyone who might have seen this to recognize the problem.

Comment: I think XxxService.conf was already part of hit. You dont have to add it again. Just commit it.

Comment: @Twinkle it didn't work. I use 'git commit', the result is all four files was committed into. Thanks!

Comment: @torek thanks for the kind reminder! It's not my personal project package, so I need to shadow some context info not related to the question itself. Thanks again : )

Comment: Then when you modify the conf file, the XML files may be automatically getting changed. Take a deep look into that

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is when you modify the conf files, it might be writing something to the XML files also. Please confirm what are the changes happened in XML files